# How to Update the dotnet core version in Azure Function

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, kudu

I was doing a kudo build for my dotnet 3.1 function app, the below is my kudo build script

```
@if "%SCM_TRACE_LEVEL%" NEQ "4" @echo off

:: ----------------------
:: KUDU Deployment Script
:: Version: 1.0.17
:: ----------------------

:: Prerequisites
:: -------------

:: Verify node.js installed
where node 2>nul >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
  goto error
)

:: Setup
:: -----

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%..\artifacts

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
)

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
)

IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
  SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

  IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
    SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
  )
)

IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
  :: Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  call npm install kudusync -g --silent
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
  SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=%appdata%\npm\kuduSync.cmd
)
IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TEMP (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TEMP=%temp%\___deployTemp%random%
  SET CLEAN_LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT_TEMP=true
)

IF DEFINED CLEAN_LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT_TEMP (
  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" rd /s /q "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
  mkdir "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
)

IF DEFINED MSBUILD_PATH goto MsbuildPathDefined
SET MSBUILD_PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
:MsbuildPathDefined

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

echo Handling .NET Web Application deployment.


:: 1. Restore NuGet packages

  call :ExecuteCmd dotnet restore "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\dotnetcore-app.sln"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: 2. Build to the temporary path

  call :ExecuteCmd dotnet publish "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\dotnetcore-app.sln" --output "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" /p:Configuration=Release


IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error


:: 5. KuduSync

  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
goto end

:: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
:ExecuteCmd
setlocal
set _CMD_=%*
call %_CMD_%
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
endlocal
echo Finished successfully.
```

The problem here is the kudo build is default talking `dotnet 5.0.204`, but I need to use the `3.1.116` SDK

```
remote: Handling .NET Web Application deployment.        
remote: Failed to add 'C:\local\UserProfile\.dotnet\tools' to the PATH environment variable. Add this directory to your PATH to use tools installed with 'dotnet tool install'.        
remote: 
remote: Welcome to .NET 5.0!        
remote: ---------------------        
remote: SDK Version: 5.0.204        
remote: 
remote: Telemetry        
remote: ---------        
remote: The .NET tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. It is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.        
remote: 
remote: Read more about .NET CLI Tools telemetry: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry        
remote: 
remote: ----------------        
remote: Installed an ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate.        
remote: To trust the certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust' (Windows and macOS only).        
remote: Learn about HTTPS: https://aka.ms/dotnet-https        
remote: ----------------        
remote: Write your first app: https://aka.ms/dotnet-hello-world        
remote: Find out what's new: https://aka.ms/dotnet-whats-new        
remote: Explore documentation: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs        
remote: Report issues and find source on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/core
```

I can see the function app is already installed with the below list of sdk's

```
C:\home\site\wwwroot>dotnet --list-sdks
1.1.14 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.522 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.109 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.113 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.115 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.116 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.201 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.203 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.204 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
```

---

Question: How can I change the dotnet version in my function to default to `3.1` and not `5.0` ?

*I already tried the [`global.json`](https://dev.to/polarbit/how-to-change-default-dotnet-sdk-version-43ph) by providing the sdk version which is not working*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every .NET uses the latest SDK installed on the machine by default, even if:

- The project targets an earlier version of the .NET runtime.
- The latest version of the .NET SDK is a preview version.

You can use the advantages of the latest SDK features and improvements while targeting earlier .NET runtime versions.

If you want **exact specific versio**n of .NET use the property `“rollforward”:”disable”`

Use below code in a global.json file

```
{
    "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.100",
    "rollForward": "disable"
    }
}
```

For more [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x)

Note: steps for migration [here](https://codetraveler.io/2021/05/28/creating-azure-functions-using-net-5/)